# How to find the average of each row in a matrix in APL? and the highest average?

Tags: matrix, apl

I'm trying to find the average of each row in a matrix.

I have two matrices.
One matrix, `NAMES`, holds a flat list of names (there are 3 names).
The other matrix,`GRADES`, contains numbers.
Each row in `GRADES` corresponds to a name in `NAMES`.

I'd like to write a function that would output:

```
Name AverageOfNumbersInRow
Name AverageOfNumbersInRow
Name AverageOfNumbersInRow
```

I'd also like to write a function that would output the Name that has the highest average:

```
Name
```

For example, for:

```
GRADES←3 4 ⍴ 98 34.5 78.9 34.7 22.3 33.9 23.8 24.11 100 89.3 92.6 87.9
NAMES←3 4 ⍴ 'JaneBob Mark'
```

I'd like

```
Mark
```

I'm using NARS2000.

Comment: @KenWhite No, APL code tends to eschew loops, and instead deal with arrays all at once. This is a sensible question as the classic APL formula for average computes the *column average*.

Comment: @Adám What's the classic APL formula for column average?

Comment: Still assuming Dyalog APL (please do state!): `+⌿÷≢`

Comment: Your output specifications are ambiguous. For the table, do you want a nested result, a heterogeneous flat matrix, or a homogenous character matrix? For the highest averaging, in case of a tie, do you want the first, any, or all names with highest average?

Answer (score 2):

Answering in Dyalog APL since the question was tagged with `APL`:

The rank operator is nice for operations like these. The block of code `(+/÷≢)⍤1` will take the *average* (*sum* divided by *length* is `(+/÷≢)`) and apply it against the rows (rank number 1) in a matrix. Example:

```
      names←'tom' 'dick' 'harry'
      numbers←3 3⍴?⍨9
      numbers
9 5 8
6 1 2
4 3 7
      names,⍪(+/÷≢)⍤1⊢numbers
 tom    7.333333333
 dick   3          
 harry  4.666666667
```

**EDIT due to additional information**

In NARS2000, to find the name with the highest average with the data in the format stated, you can use `{⍺⌷⍨(⊢⍳⌈/)(+/÷≢)⍤1⊢⍵}`:

```
      GRADES←3 4 ⍴ 98 34.5 78.9 34.7 22.3 33.9 23.8 24.11 100 89.3 92.6 87.9
      NAMES←3 4 ⍴ 'JaneBob Mark'
      f←{⍺⌷⍨(⊢⍳⌈/)(+/÷≢)⍤1⊢⍵}
      NAMES f GRADES
Mark
```

Comment: Thanks! As a followup question, how would you return just the name with the highest average? (in your case: tom)

Comment: @judah Either add that to your original question or post a separate one. Note that the code for finding the name with highest average won't resemble this code much.

Comment: You may want to revise this answer in light of the names' matrix having turned out to be flat.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in NARS2000.

"b" is a column of 6 names, "a" is one 6 rows matrix of 5 votes, "c" would be the mean each row of "a"

```
  b←⍪"one" "two" "treqq" "qu" "cin" "six" 
  a←6 5⍴↑,/{⍵?10}¨30⍴1
  a
10 8 3 2 6
 3 9 9 1 7
 4 4 9 1 9
 2 1 8 1 8
 5 1 7 2 6
 3 9 4 4 9
  c←(2⌷⍴a)÷⍨+/a
  c
5.8 5.8 5.4 4 4.2 5.8 
  b,c
 one   5.8 
 two   5.8 
 treqq 5.4 
 qu    4   
 cin   4.2 
 six   5.8 
  ⎕fmt  ,b[(+/c[↑⍒c]=c)↑⍒c;]
┌3───────────────────┐
│┌3───┐ ┌3───┐ ┌3───┐│
││ one│ │ two│ │ six││
│└────┘ └────┘ └────┘2
└∊───────────────────┘
```